# Get values from collection Cloud Firestore based on a filtering query with several .where

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

From the collection "matches" filtered by "league_id" if equal to 468 then if matches array in any position jornada array contains "Fri May 01 2020".

I've tried this but no joy.
I belive that, If there is a way to combine the 2nd and 3th where in one will do the trick....

```
let query = await db.firestore().collection("matches");

query = await query.where("league_id", "==", "468");
console.log(query);

query.where("matches", "array-contains", "jornada"); //2nd
query
  .where("jornada", "array-contains", today)//3th
  .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
    console.log(querySnapshot);

    var cities = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

      console.log(doc.data());


    });
  });
```

Comment: If you have mulitple where clauses, you need to chain them together:  `collection.where().where().where()`

Comment: Hey thx for the fast responce. I've tried it but this is what i get **Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Invalid query. You cannot use more than one 'array-contains' filter.**

I need to find the way to combine the 2nd and 3th where so it can return me the desire **jornada**

Comment: OK, sounds like the query you're trying to do isn't supported by Firestore. Please edit the question to say more about the structure of your documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query that you perform:

```
query = await query.where("league_id", "==", "468");
```

Will work perfectly fine because you have a `league_id` property that holds the `468` value, however, the addition of the following call:

```
query.where("matches", "array-contains", "jornada");
```

It will not work because you are telling Firestore to return all documents that contain in the `matches` array the `jornada` String. This is not possible because in the `matches` array, you are **not** storing String values. The `matches` is actually an array that holds objects, objects which in terms contain some properties of type array. Such kinds of queries actually are not supported by Firestore.

What can you instead, is to create another array property within your document that will actually hold String values. Add in that array the exact String values on which you want to filter the data and the second query will work too.

Comment: Can you give me an example please based on the structure i have in the firestore, check the image. Matches is an array holding different jornadas.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you cannot achieve that with the actual structure. You should change that array to hold String values or create another array with String values and change the query `.where("newArray", "array-contains", "jornada")`, right?